# RPG text game store amendment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys im new to programming and I am struggling with an amendment of currency in the store. The code runs but the amount of currency amended is the same for each item, although I have coded it to take different amounts for different items.

I have tried amending each amount but it takes the amount from the first item and applies it to all items

```
import math
import random
import os
import sys
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()
displayw = 800
displayh = 600
#pygame.mixer.music.load('')
#pygame.mixer.music.play('')
#pygame.mixer.music.pause('')
#pygame.mixer.music.stop('')
#pygame.mixer.Sound('')
#win = pygame.display.set_mode((displayw, displayh))
#pygame.display.set_caption('The Lodge')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

inventory = []

###################### ITEM LIST

lighter = 'lighter'
axe = 'axe'
bandage = 'bandage'
jacket = 'jacket'

###################### CLASSES

class user:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.gold = 100
        self.lvl = 1

class enemy:
    def __init__(self, health, goldg):
        self.name = 'Monster LVL 1'
        self.health = 25
        self.goldg = 15

###################### MAIN SKELETON INTRO ############################################################################################

def main():
    global player
    global weapon
    global item
    global itemadd
    print('# version 1.0.0, decription - multichoice text based RPG, enter numbers or KEYWORDS')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('\t\t########## Chapter 1 ##########')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('What is your name?')
    option = input(':> ')
    player = user(option)
    print('Be careful', player.name, ', enemies can be anywhere!')
    run()

def run():
    print('\t\t########## THE LODGE ##########')
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
    print('Hi', player.name, 'Welcome to the lodge, here are your stats')
    print('\n\t\t', player.name, '|  Health', player.health, '|  Gold', player.gold, '|  LVL', player.lvl)
    print('')
    print('Here is what you have in your inventory: ', inventory)
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system('cls')
    print('The room is well lit from the fire burning, there is no one in here other than the receptionist, hunched over the log counter reading an old paper.')
    print('You approach the receptionist cautiously...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('He looks overly tired..like he hasnt slept in weeks. Im not surprised with this place though, it could do with a real good makeover')
    time.sleep(3)
    os.system('cls')
    print('**Receptionist** - phewwww, you must be ', player.name, '.Your room is ready..feel free to look around before you go up. We have some new things in the store')
    option1 = input('Where do you want to go?\n1. Your room\n2. The store\n3. Look around\n:> ')
    if option1 == '1':
        lodgeroom()
    elif option1 == '2':
        store()
    elif option1 == '3':
        explore()
    else:
        print(error)
        lodge()

def error():
    print('Oops thats not an option, please enter a valid choice')

########################################### AFTER SKELETON #########################################################################################

def explore(): ###kitchen ## landing ## cabinet ## currentroom ## bookcase
    print('**Receptionist** - There are plenty of books to read if you are bored.')
    print('The room is well maintained and the fire is still burning hot. You see there are 2 chairs placed facing each other with a table directly inbetween them.')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Over on the other side of the room is the entrance to the Kitchen just besides the stair case that leads to your room.')
    print('You notice a bookshelf on the right stacked with leather bound books next to the exit sign that leads to the court yard')
    time.sleep(4)
    option1 = input('Where do you want to explore?\n:> ')
    if option1 =='kitchen' or 'Kitchen':
        kitchen()
    elif option1 == 'bookcase' or 'Bookcase':
        bookcase()
    elif option1 == 'armchair' or 'Armchair' or 'arm chair' or 'Arm chair' or 'Arm Chair':
        puzzle()
    elif option1 == 'court yard' or 'Court yard':
        courtyard()
    if option1 == 'exit' or 'Exit':
        courtyard()
    else:
        print(error)

def lodgeroom():
    print('\t\t########## LODGE BEDROOM ##########')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('The door creeks open as the cold brass handle rattles in your hand. The smell of pine sniks deep into your nostrils')
    print('This is your room, you can save your game here or rest to gain health')
    time.sleep(3)
    option1 = input('1. Rest\n2.Save\n3.Exit\n:> ')
    if option1 == '1':
        print('You take off your clothes and lay down to res in the old quilted bed, when you wake you will be back in the lodge. Dont worry your belongings are safe here')
        if player.health < 100:
            player.health = 100
        lodge()
    if option1 == '2':
        pass
    if option1 == '3':
        print('You close the door behind you and return to the lodge main room')
        lodge()
    else:
        print(error)


############################################## MAIN STORE ###########################################################################################

def store():
    print('\t\t########## Store ##########')
    print('Items you already have are listed below\n', inventory)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Items available\n\t\t1. lighter: 15\n\t\t2. axe: 70\n\t\t3. bandage: 50\n\t\t4. jacket: 500\n\t\t5. EXIT')
    time.sleep(3)
    buy = input('What do you need?\n:> ')
    if buy == '1' and player.gold > 15:
        blighter()
    if buy == '2' and player.gold > 70:
        baxe()
    if buy == '3' and player.gold > 50:
        bbandage()
    if buy == '4' and player.gold > 500:
        bjacket()
    if buy == '5':
        lodge()
    else:
        print('You do not have enough gold to buy this item, please come back when you have enough!')



########################################## STORE END #############################################################################

def lodge():
    print('\t\t########## THE LODGE ##########')
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
    print('Hi', player.name, 'Welcome back to the lodge, here are your stats')
    print('\n\t\t', player.name, '|  Health', player.health, '|  Gold', player.gold, '|  LVL', player.lvl)
    print('')
    print('Here is what you have in your inventory: ', inventory)
    option1 = input('Where do you want to go?\n1. Your room\n2. The store\n3. Look around\n4. Exit to the Court Yard\n:> ')
    if option1 == '1':
        lodgeroom()
    elif option1 == '2':
        store()
    elif option1 == '3':
        explore()
    elif option1 == '4':
        courtyard()
    else:
        print(error)
        lodge()

def courtyard():
    print('A Monster is approaching!\nIts dark outside and you can just about make the shape of the creature. It is on all fours progressing slowly towards you...you turn to run back inside and notice a sharp stick on the ground')
    option = input('Do you grab the stick to "fight" or do you "run" back inside?\n:> ')
    if option == 'fight' or 'Fight':
        print('As you bend down to pick up the stick the beast starts moving quicker. You can hear it drawing close. Just as it is about to pounce you turn and jam the stick through its neck')
        print('The beast bleeds out and dies, it looks like some sort of hybrid between a wolf and a human')
        player.gold =+ enemy.goldg
        print('You have gained', enemy.goldg, 'gold and Leveled up!')
        player.lvl += 1
        lodge()
    if option == 'run' or 'Run':
        print('As you go to run back inside the beast pounches on your back taking a chunk of skin')
        player.health -= enemy.health
        print('You should go get some rest to recover your health!')
        lodge()
    else:
        print(error)


##################### MAIN STORY LINES #####################

def kitchen():
    pass

def puzzle():
    pass

def armchair():
    pass

def bookcase():
    pass

###################### ITEM LIST #########################

def blighter():
    print('You bought a lighter!')
    player.gold -= 15
    inventory.append(lighter)


def baxe():
    print('You bought an Axe!')
    player.gold -= 70
    inventory.append(axe)


def bbandage():
    print('You bought a bandage!')
    player.gold -= 50
    inventory.append(bandage)


def bjacket():
    print('You bought a jacket')
    player.gold -= 500
    inventory.append(jacket)


main()
```

no errors are showing but I expect the amount of currency to amend correctly

Comment: Oops.. `store` calls `blighter` and `blighter` calls `store` add the same time!

Comment: If I call any of the other items to be purchased it still takes the amount of blighter. If I get rid of store() at the end of the purchase will it correct the problem?

Comment: `lodge` function definition missing

Comment: I dont think all of the code will fit on here I can try and edit it to show the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of return to store at the end of each function, you need to use an infinity loop to be always in store. Let's check below snippet.

```py
def blighter():
    print('You bought a lighter!')
    player.gold -= 15
    inventory.append(lighter)

def baxe():
    print('You bought an Axe!')
    player.gold -= 70
    inventory.append(axe)

def bbandage():
    print('You bought a bandage!')
    player.gold -= 50
    inventory.append(bandage)

def bjacket():
    print('You bought a jacket')
    player.gold -= 500
    inventory.append(jacket)

def lodge():
    pass

def store():
    min_gold_list = [15, 70, 50, 500, None]
    function_list = [blighter, baxe, bbandage, bjacket, lodge]

    while True:
        print('\t\t########## Store ##########')
        print('Items you already have are listed below\n', inventory)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Items available\n\t\t1. lighter: 15\n\t\t2. axe: 70\n\t\t3. bandage: 50\n\t\t4. jacket: 500\n\t\t5. EXIT')
        time.sleep(3)

        item = int(input('What do you need?\n:> '))
        if 1 <= item <= 5:
            idx = item - 1
            if item == 5 or player.gold > min_gold_list[idx]:
                function_list[idx]()
            else:
                print('You do not have enough gold for this item, come back soon')
        else:
            print('Item not found!')
```

Comment: Thanks for the amendment. I have tried this and after a purchase it amends the amount but runs "You do not have enough gold for this item, come back soon" immediately after the purchase...

Comment: `if buy == '5':` -->  `elif buy == '5':`  - this code is dangerous . if you areinthe lodge and go to the shop you leave to the lodge and go into to shop you have plenty of  funciton call stacks upon each other:  lodge->shop_>lodge->shop etc. Lookup return - your whole code will get very confusiong if you have 54 functions calling itself and lopping into each other...